# Linux bash command that returns where two strings differ

Tags: linux, string, bash, command-line, difference

So, I've been googling around, and also searching in more detail on stack overflow, but I just can't seem to find an easy way of doing exactly this:

I want to know in what way two strings (without whitespace) differ, and simply print what that exact difference is.

*E.g.:*

```
Input 1 > "Chocolatecakeflavour"
Input 2 > "Chocolateflavour"

Output: "cake"
```

I've tried doing this with diff and dwdiff, cmp, and other known bash commands that popped into mind, but I just couldn't get this exact result.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is a hard problem, depending on the amount of differences and the length of the input text.  Have a look at diff, match and patch algorithms they might set you on the right path.

Comment: What should the output be if input 1 is "foo" and input 2 is "bar"?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `diff` with `fold` and `awk` like ths:

```
s="Chocolatecakeflavour"
r="Chocolateflavour"

diff <(fold -w1 <<< "$s") <(fold -w1 <<< "$r") | awk '/[<>]/{printf $2}'
cake
```

- `fold -w1` is to split input string character by character (one in each line)
- `diff` is to get difference in both lists (1 char in each line)
- `awk '/[<>]/{printf $2}'` is to suppress `<` OR `>` from diff'e output and print everything in same line

---

**EDIT:** As per OP's comments below if strings are in different lines of a file then use:

```
f=file
diff <(fold -w1 <(sed '2q;d' $f)) <(fold -w1 <(sed '3q;d' $f)) | awk '/[<>]/{printf $2}'
cake
```

Comment: Somehow, for my specific needs this doesn't do what I want. (although I dont understand how) My input 1 and input 2 are on different lines in a file, so I use sed '2q;d' and sed '3q;d' to get them from the file like this:

diff --normal <(fold -w1 <<< <(echo sed '2q;d' AdaptiveMutants)) <(fold -w1 <<< <(echo sed '3q;d' AdaptiveMutants)) | awk '/[<>]/{printf $2}'

Somehow though, this returns a '32', which is definitely not part of the input strings.